# DbUpdateConcurrencyException in saving data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with entity framework and when I call context.entities method, even if database have new value it gives me old value.

For example, I have column status and it is updated to 9 by a console application(other application but uses same method to update) and when I call context.entities it gives 0 which was the value before update operation.

One thing I want highlight is that when console application update a record it throws DbUpdateConcurrencyException. That method handles that exception by following code.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SaveChanges()
{
    int count = 0;
    bool saveFailed;

    do
    {
        saveFailed = false;
        try
        {
            count = await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            saveFailed = true;
            // Update original values from the database 
            var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues());
        }
    }
    while (saveFailed);

    return count;
}

//update code
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var timeNow = DateTime.Now;
        var entities = repo.All()
                            .Where(p => p.CreatedAt.HasValue &&
                                        p.Status == Infrastructure.Enum.Status.New || 
                                        p.Status == Infrastructure.Enum.Status.Pending)
                            .ToList()
                            .Where(p => timeNow.Subtract(p.CreatedAt.Value.DateTime) >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        foreach (var item in entities)
        {
            //update
            item.Status= Status.Cancelled;
        }

        await repo.SaveChanges();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}).Wait();
```

Comment: The code you posted will simply revert any changes in the entity when a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is raised, so you'll have to fix the cause for the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` so that your changes can be saved to the database. Take a look at the message of the  `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, that should actually indicate the cause for the error.

Comment: @bassfader Thanks for reply but if it reverts all values then in database why I see new values. I have updated question so you can see code for updating.

Comment: I fixed it by using AsNoTracking(), as while fetching list it cached the data first time and after all subsequent request same data was returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using AsNoTracking(), as while fetching list it cached the data first time and after all subsequent request same data was returned. –

Comment: AsNoTracking() Fixed issue but causing new problem as EF cannot identify if records need to be updated or not, it every time inserts new records, which is not needed.

Comment: You have to specify if is an update or insert: context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added, or  context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; and use the respective, add or attach.